# Pycharm at mac - disable square symbol before ''(quotation) at pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Whenever I type simple or double quotation in a file using pycharm, a square symbol like this  appears and I have to remove it to run my code otherwise the code fails. Does someone knows how to disable this symbol at pycharm? I am using it on mac.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use single or double quotes in a normal editor?

Comment: Hi, in a normal editor this symbol does not appears. I think this is must be some config at pycharm, but I haven't found anything related to this in the internet. I also uninstalled and installed again the pycharm, but it still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing a known PyCharm (JDK 11) issue on macOS: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1311

For the workaround:

- either switch PyCharm to run under JDK 8 (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)
- or add `com.jetbrains.use.old.keyevent.processing=true` to **Help | Edit Custom Properties** and restart

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your help. After add the parameter on Edit Custom Properties it worked.